# Unzip file contents, but without creating archive folder

Tags: cp, zip

I have a file myarchive.zip that contains many directories, files, etc. Let's say this myarchive.zip file lives in a directory called "b". Well, when I use the "unzip myarchive.zip" command, the system creates a directory by default called "myarchive" with the contents of the zip file. I do **not** want the system to create this "myarchive" directory - I just want the contents to be extracted to directory "b". Is this possible?

What I've been doing now is simply issuing a "cp" command to copy the files from the newly created directory (in this case "myarchive" to "b") to where I want them.

Comment: By default, `unzip` doesn't create a directory. Your zip file probably has the directory at its top level.

Comment: You could use `mv` instead of `cp`. `mv archive/* .; rmdir archive/` or similar.

Comment: @ChrisDown: my archive had only files inside, no subfolders, and yet `unzip` with no arguments extracted it into `<archivename>/`. Debian 12.

Answer (score 85):

My version of `unzip` has a `-j` option to not create any directory.

So

```
unzip -j /path/to/file.zip
```

Will extract all the files into the current directory without restoring the directory structure stored in the `zip` file.

If you want to only remove one level of directories from the archive, (extract `myarchive/dir/file` as `dir/file`, not `file`), you could use `bsdtar` (which does supports `zip` files in addition to `tar` files) instead and its `-s` option.

```
bsdtar -xf /path/to/file.zip -s'|[^/]*/||'
```

Comment: When using `-j` the archive directory structure is not recreated and all files are deposited in the extraction folder. This means *ALL* subfolders are dropped. So if you would have `zip/A/f1`, `zip/A/B/f2` and `zip/A/B/C/f3` you would end up with a single folder with f1, f2, f3. It gets funky if you have files with the same name in different subfolders. Usually you want to just drop the top folder not the entire directory structure.

Comment: @CristianVrabie, well that's exactly what I'm saying in the answer. I've added a bsdtar alternative for what you're asking. See edit.

Comment: How could we get the file names extracted inside the `/path/to/file.zip`

Comment: "gets funky" - THAT is an understatement!

Answer (score 15):

Looks like this is really simple with [bsdtar](https://www.libarchive.org/) :

`bsdtar --strip-components=1 -xvf file.zip`

Answer (score 14):

What the accepted answer doesn't specify how to do, as you say in the question, if you still want to extract to a specific folder without using the folders paths stored in the zip files, you can use the `-j` option with `-d` option in this way:

```
unzip -j /path/to/file.zip -d other_folder
```

or for your case

```
unzip -j myarchive.zip -d b
```

Comment: You're right that you can do that; but it won't create the subdirectories so you still have to incorporate another step; I'm pretty sure the OP wants to rename the root directory of the archive to another name but keep the remaining structure under that directory.

Comment: Very useful addition to the answer here though, this is the detail I was just searching for and I'm glad I scrolled down. More upvotes here folks.

Answer (score 7):

Easily to do it with tips create temp folder then move files back to current directory ex:

```bsh
unzip myfile.zip -d ./tmp
mv ./tmp/*/* .
```

Comment: How do you handle directories that are already present in `/tmp` before you extract the archive?

Comment: this is ./tmp not /tmp of system . We create tmp directory inside storaged  zip file... so you can see all directories inside

Comment: The question also applies to `./tmp`. If it already exists, any files it contains will be moved along with the archive’s contents. One fix for that is to use `mktemp -d`.

Comment: This approach works for me, although I prefer `tmp=$(mktemp -d ./tmp-XXXX)` instead of `./tmp`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in the `b` directory already:

```
tar zxvf myarchive.zip --strip-components=1
```

Otherwise:

```
tar zxvf b/myarchive.zip --strip-components=1 -C b/
```

Answer (score -1):

If performing `unzip myarchive.zip` produces a directory `myarchive` with everything in it, then that means the creator of the zip file actually performed zip on that directory.

The only way to create what you want is to just move all the contents outside the directory after you perform `unzip`:

`[user@host]:some/path/b$ unzip myarchive.zip`

`[user@host]:some/path/b$ ls` {*shows directory `myarchive`*}

`[user@host]:some/path/b$ mv myarchive/* .`

`[user@host]:some/path/b$ rm -R myarchive`

`[user@host]:some/path/b$ ls` {*shows first level of myarchive (directly in `b`)*}

Comment: you also need a `mv myarchive/.* .` to move all the hidden files like .gitignore and .htaccess.

Comment: @KinjalDixit That was my thinking too; Antoine there's a fatal flaw in your example as Kinjai points out: because you use *`rm -R`* and because you're not using *`ls -a`* you're not showing if there are any dot files; now what happens when you run *`rm -R`* and there are dot files? You've not copied them so they're lost. You really should fix that and maybe explain the difference because it's something that will trip up newbies quite a lot; and consider this: what if it's not an archive they have? Or what if they add to the command to delete the archive once it's uncompressed?

Comment: Otoh *`rmdir`* would make sure it's empty first... But if the user doesn't know about dot files it'd confuse them.